# How to reboot a WindowsCE5 device?

Tags: shortcuts, reboot, windows-ce

Is there a way to force a device running Windows CE 5.0 to reboot? I remember Ctrl+Alt+Del from the old days on PC's, but I don't know if there's a keyboard-combination I could use on this [Datalogic BlackJet](http://www.mobile.datalogic.com/Datalogic-JET_prd_prd14_4_1.html), and I can't seem to find a reset pin-hole. I tried taking the battery out, and waiting a few hours, but that totally reset the device from ROM, undoing all setup I'd done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it in the mean time (in the manual...), it's F1+SCAN+On/Off for a warm boot and F1+F2+SCAN+On/Off for a cold boot.